# What does Tyler Winklevoss mean about this claim that you can borrow money from your Bitcoin without spending them?

Tags: loans, lending, interest

Here: https://youtu.be/GWBZisZtfeY?t=232

> And today, you can borrow off your Bitcoin, get the cash, spend it without selling the Bitcoin

I want to do this. I need to do this. How exactly? Where? Who? Do they require KYC/AML BS? (Besides them knowing my bank account/name.)

So let's say that I have X BTC. Now I want to get "free income" from those without spending them. How do I do this, exactly? Is he really serious?

(I would be asking Mr. Winklevoss himself, but I have a feeling that he would not see it or at least not respond.)

Comment: Hi Jaes B., since this statement seems to be provided without any further context, it's not clear how anyone besides Mr. Winklevoss could know which service he was exactly thinking about or what properties that service has. Somebody recently asked about a similar topic here, though: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100935/5406

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do this. I need to do this. How exactly? Where? Who? Do they require KYC/AML BS? (Besides them knowing my bank account/name.)

Although I am not sure which service was Tyler WinkleVoss referring to. You can borrow stablecoins, L-BTC etc. on HodlHodl with bitcoin as collateral locked in multisig. No KYC is involved in the process.

1. Contract is created and HodlHodl generates a unique escrow.
   Borrower deposits Bitcoin as Сollateral into the escrow, directly from their wallet.
2. Lender transfers the Loan amount to the Borrower, as according to the Contract.
3. When the Loan is repaid, the Lender releases the Bitcoin back to the Borrower's wallet.

You can read more about it here: https://lend.hodlhodl.com/faq/basics